# How to use nested for loops to create FAQ?

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I am creating a list of frequently asked question with questions and explanations. By default i want to show questions only.

If a user clicks on a particular question, then only its answer should expand, closing all the other answers.

I'm using nested loops.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script>
    function display(k){
        for(i=1;i<=k;i++){
            for(j=i; j<=i; j++){
                document.getElementById('sol'+j).style.display="block";
                }
                document.getElementById('sol'+i).style.display="none";
        }
    }
</script>

<body>

    <div id="faq1" onclick="display(1)">FAQ 1: Return Policy
        <div id="sol1" style="display:  none;">
            Customer can replace products within 30 days from the days of purchase.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="faq2" onclick="display(2)">FAQ 2: Warranty
        <div id="sol2" style="display:  none;">
            Warranty would be solely fulfiled by the brand company.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="faq3" onclick="display(3)">FAQ 3: Extended Warranty
        <div id="sol3" style="display:  none;">
            Customer can apply for extended warranty for their products provided their products fulfil the TOS.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="faq4" onclick="display(4)">FAQ 4: Address
        <div id="sol4" style="display:  none;">
            Our company is situated in the heart of the city Jammu.
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

i tried different combinations, but i'm stuck.

Comment: why you are using faq1 as id for all divs? u cant have same id for more then 1 element

Comment: Ids are always unique.

Comment: `for(j=i; j<=i; j++)` – this doesn't really need a loop does it? It will only execute once, for `j = i`. Also, you'll always show the div, then immediately hide it on the next line. You need to show the open div **after** you hide the others.

Answer (score 1):

A much easier approach would be to add a CSS class for all the questions and for all the answers.

Then specify, for example let's use `.answer`, that the class elements are hidden (`.answer {display: none}`). Then, use JS to create an event listener for all the question class elements, and upon clicking just toggle it's child div (.answer).

That way you'd avoid many errors and bad design choices you have in your code, like: repeated ids, inline styles, separate onclick attributes for every question div, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Add jquery and make it simple.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Hutm/3/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.faq').click(function(){
        if($(this).find('div:first-child').is(':visible'))
            $(this).find('div:first-child').hide('slow');
        else
        {
            $('.faq').children().hide('slow');
            $(this).find('div:first-child').show('slow');
        }
    });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is here

```
<div id="faq1" class="faqcls">FAQ 1: Return Policy
    <div id="sol1" class="solcls" style="display:  none;">
        Customer can replace products within 30 days from the days of purchase.
    </div>
</div>

<div id="faq2" class="faqcls" >FAQ 2: Warranty
    <div id="sol2" class="solcls" style="display:  none;">
        Warranty would be solely fulfiled by the brand company.
    </div>
</div>

<div id="faq3" class="solcls" class="faqcls">FAQ 3: Extended Warranty
    <div id="sol3" style="display:  none;">
        Customer can apply for extended warranty for their products provided their products fulfil the TOS.
    </div>
</div>

<div id="faq4" class="solcls" class="faqcls">FAQ 4: Address
    <div id="sol4" style="display:  none;">
        Our company is situated in the heart of the city Jammu.
    </div>
</div>
```

and javascript is here

```
$(document).on('click','.faqcls',function() {
    $(this).find('.solcls').slideToggle();
```

});

and jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/A3Pwg/

Comment: You forgot to mention this requires jQuery which the OP isn't using.

Answer (score 0):

try using  `document.getElementsByClassName` :  see this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zPs9p/)**

```
function display(k){        
    arr = document.getElementsByClassName('sol');
    for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i].style.display="none";
    }
    document.getElementById('sol'+k).style.display="block";
}
```

css:

```
.sol{
    display: none;
}
```

and add class `sol` to divs:

```
<div id="sol1" class="sol">
      Customer can replace products within 30 days from the days of purchase.
  </div>
```